# How to you append rows from an existing dataframe to a new dataframe based on a column value?

Tags: r

I would like to do something like the following where I append a row from an existing dataframe to a new dataframe if it contains a particular value (in this case "setosa"). For the rows that don't contain "setosa," I would like to randomly sample and populate the rest of the rows until I get a 50/50 split between those rows with "setosa" and those with something that's not "setosa."

Here is my start so far.

```
data(iris)

dataset_new <- iris %>%
  ifelse(Species == "setosa", rbind()?, nrow()?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using {dplyr}:

```
library(dplyr)

df_setosa <- iris %>%
  filter(Species == "setosa")
  
dataset_new <- iris %>%
  filter(Species != "setosa") %>%
  slice_sample(n = nrow(df_setosa)) %>%
  bind_rows(df_setosa)

# check results
dataset_new %>%
  count(Species == "setosa")
#   Species == "setosa"  n
# 1               FALSE 50
# 2                TRUE 50
```

Answer (score 2):

You can subset rows that are `setosa`, and sample rows from non-`setosa` species, with size of the number of `setosa` rows.

```r
#setosa rows
seto <- iris[iris$Species == "setosa",]

#random subsample of non-setosa rows of size n("setosa") 
nonseto <- iris[sample(which(iris$Species != "setosa"), size = length(which(iris$Species == "setosa"))),]

dataset_new <- rbind(seto, nonseto)
```

Answer (score 2):

One liner solution with base R only:

```
iris[c(which(iris$Species == "setosa"), 
       sample(which(iris$Species != "setosa"),
              size = sum(iris$Species == "setosa"))), ]
```

Explanation: We're selecting a set of rows by concatenating with `c()` all row numbers which `Species` value equals `"setosa"` and a sample of rows that have `Species != "setosa"`, with the same size as the count of rows that had `Species == "setosa"`, without replacement (`sample()` function standard).